# Null Pointer Exception after inflation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

Below is my code for a fragment I have, I am trying to set the text of a textView in the view, I was under the impression that as long as you inflate the view first, it would not return null as it has been created. That according to the fragment life cycle.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View loginFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
        TextView imei = (TextView) loginFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_id);
        imei.setText("IMEI: ");
        return loginFragmentView;
    }
```

This does cause the application to crash with the nullPointerException, does anyone know how to get around this. Is there a method I can override that will only be called one the fragment lifecycle has finished.

I also tried to put it in onResume() as that is right at the end of the lifecycle buthad same result. Any Idea?

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Your device ID:"
        android:id="@+id/txt_id_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Fetching ID..."
        android:id="@+id/txt_device_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_id_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
05-22 19:40:02.230 2799-2799/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: alertssystem.rrr.lsa13.rrr_alerts, PID: 2799
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.TextView.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                     at alertssystem.rrr.lsa13.rrr_alerts.login_layout_fragment.onCreateView(login_layout_fragment.java:24)
                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Make sure there is a `TextView` with the id `txt_device_id` in the `login_layout` layout.

Comment: your stacktrace ?! and where you getting the npe?

Comment: Wrong one, I re-edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you are declaring the TextView too early according to the fragment lifycycle, so, instead of declaring it at `onCreateView`, declare it at `onViewCreated`, so it will be:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View loginFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
        return loginFragmentView;
    }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View loginFragmentView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      TextView imei = (TextView) loginFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_id);
      imei.setText("IMEI: ");
  }
```

Comment: Still returns a null pointer. :(
Exactly same as above.

Comment: the TextView name is `txt_id_title` not `txt_device_id`

Comment: Look under it, don't get confused with the android:layout_below bit,

Comment: So,  make sure what layout you are running this at, if you are providing more than layout according to width like `layout-sw600dp` may be you are not providing this TextView inside this layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, no idea what you mean.

Comment: how many `loginFragmentView` you have ?!! only one in layouts folder?!! or you have a lot of it according to layout width ?

Comment: WOW! OMG I am blind.

Comment: I was doing this code in LoginFragment java file and xml was in register. So the code was not taking place, as register was not created yet from login. :/

Comment: great, I'm happy I could help in solving your problem :), you have to watch for that in the future

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace I guess your loginFragmentView doesn't have child of type  textview with id *txt_device_id* so check if in inflate method you are passing correct layout name which contains textview with id you are trying to find

Comment: It is definitely in there. see layout markup in question.

Comment: you can check whether your loginViewFragment contains that view or not by putting break point at  TextView imei = (TextView) loginFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_id);   and evaluate expression. check the childs of loginViewFragment